# How do I root my Nook HD?

Tags: rooting, nook-hd

I checked [The Master List of Rooting Techniques](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device), and found nothing. This [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2062613) looked promising.

Comment: What's wrong with that post?  Flash CWM then flash the root package.

Comment: Like @MatthewRead I'm a bit confused by your question. Is that thread on xda not working for you, if so what are the errors you are getting? If you wish this is another method: [NOOK HD:
All-in-One, ROOT+manual OTA+Enable Unknown Source+GAPPS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2030469)

Comment: It did eventually work, and I just wanted StackExchange to be a good source on this. I guess I'll answer myself  now...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)

Comment: 'Starting Jan 2012 we are going to allow one "How to root?" question per device. Just search for [rooting] and your device or refer to the index below. If the question doesn't exist yet, create one and add it to this index.' - I've added a link to the list, as instructed, on *How do I root my Android device*.

Comment: You're right, this post is fine. Thanks for coming back with the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To root a Nook HD or HD+ you can use **Clockworkmod** (***CWM***) Recovery, a tool to install modifications to an Android device.

Follow the instructions on this **[XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2062613)** to create bootable Micro SD from one the provided images.

I used *Win32DiskImager* on a Windows XP net-book with a built-in card-reader to burn a SD with the ***NookHD-bootable-CWM-6025-for-emmc-stock-small-rev2.zip*** image. And I copied ***NookHD-HDplus-Universal-Root-rev1.zip*** into it.

Once I could boot my Nook from the CWM SD I made a backup and used "install zip from SD" to apply the *NookHD-HDplus-Universal-Root-rev1.zip*

More information and tips to be found at the [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2062613)

Comment: Might be best to add this to the [community wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device/1185#1185)

Comment: Hi @t0mm13b, I followed this instructions: 'Starting Jan 2012 we are going to allow one "How to root?" question per device. Just search for [rooting] and your device or refer to the index below. If the question doesn't exist yet, create one and add it to this index.'

Comment: That's great :)